# Using the Angular Slice Pipe with " , " and " ... "

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I wanted to use the Slice Pipe so a list will stop showing after 5 elements, so far so good only problem is I want to use a "  , " to seperate them and after the 5th element I want to have this" ... " I tried various things like a custom pipe or the truncate Pipe but nothing helped me. Can someone maybe give me a pointer where my mistake lies?

```
    <div class="farmer-common-products "  
*ngFor="let commonCategory of farm.commonProductCategories  | slice:0: 5 " >


                      {{ commonCategory.name }}
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you can use local variables in your `*ngFor` (see [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)). Like in the following example:

```
<div class="farmer-common-products "  
     *ngFor="let commonCategory of farm.commonProductCategories | slice:0: 5; let last = last">

    {{ commonCategory.name }}
    <span *ngIf="!laste">,</span>
    <span *ngIf="last && farm.commonProductCategories.length">...</span>
</div>
```

Or you can implement a `Pipe`, which returns you a string in your desired format:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'formatCategories'
})
export class FormatCategoriesPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(arr: any[]): string {
        let text = arr.slice(0, 5).join(',');
        if (arr.length > 5) {
            text += '...';
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```